# How to calculate the utc time and the local time from google map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, utc, localtime

How can I calculate the utc time and the local time from google map?

For instance, this is the json result from google,

```
{
   "dstOffset" : 0.0,
   "rawOffset" : -28800.0,
   "status" : "OK",
   "timeZoneId" : "America/Los_Angeles",
   "timeZoneName" : "Pacific Standard Time"
}
```

My function,

```
   function calcTime(offset) {
        var d = new Date();
        var utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
        var nd = new Date(utc + (1000*offset));

        return nd.toLocaleString();
    }
```

Usage,

```
// Calculate the time.
var local = calcTime(-28800.0);
var utc = calcTime(0.0);
```

Am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use the Timezone API offered by Google to calculate the local time. While requesting the data from this API you have to make a GET request to the following API.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/outputFormat?parameters
```

**EDIT**

In the parameters the required values are the coordinates of the location in lat/lng and the timestamp. The **timestamp** is always the UTC time which you can get by going on this [link](http://www.epochconverter.com/). You can directly put that in the timestamp variable as UTC and get the response.

To calculate the **local time** you have to calculate the sum of the timestamp parameter, and the dstOffset and rawOffset fields from the result. The dstOffset and the rawOffset fields are the JSON responses obtained after you send a request.

Comment: thanks for the answer. `localTime := time.Date...` I think this is not javascript. I am using javascript sorry.

Comment: See the edited answer. You do not need to write a Javascript function either. You can get the timestamp directly from the link mentioned in the answer and get the UTC that you can pass as timestamp in the Timezone API.

Comment: @AniV when you add timestamp (UTC), dstOffset (daylight savings offset), and rawOffset (the offset from UTC) and create Date such as: new Date(timestamp + dstOffset + rawOffset * 1000), it gives you the correct numerical value for the local hour, but it's timezone says UTC, which is wrong. I found that I had to extract the numerical values from the google response and use moment-timezone JS to get the values in the correct time zone. 

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

a `Date()` is nothing more than the number of milliseconds since 1970-1-1 in UTC. if you add something to it, you're changing that number, which will screw up all your calculations.

How that number is displayed (ie timezone) is a formatting issue.
This is why moment.js exists. It makes datetimes human readable without changing the underlying data.

From their docs: var `c = moment.tz(1403454068850, "America/Toronto");`